# How do I echo text from db as asterisks?

Tags: php

I have a name that I want to encode until someone logs into the site.

```
<?php get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_first_name', true );?> //shows the name jimmy. 

If the user is not logged in, I'd like it to show ***** // the asterisks being the same length as the name.
```

I just can't seem to figure this out. I've tried the str_replace and can't seem to make it work. I'm a beginner with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$name=get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_first_name', true );
echo str_repeat("*", strlen($name));
```

It will repeatedly print `*` as many times  (equal to the number of characters in your string). You can then put that in your `if` condition which checks if the user is logged in.

Ok here goes that condition too, enjoy :)

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo $name;
} else {
    echo str_repeat("*", strlen($name));
}
```

**[Reference: is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)**

Comment: So simple, I would have never figured that out lol. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it.